# cakephp - compare table with a similar table with uppercase name from another database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a table "assets" having (id, name, serial) in my database, and a read-only table ASSET (in uppercase) (ID, NAME, SERIAL) stored in an external database (declared in app.php)

in my app.php, I put the connections:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'db1',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ],

    'external_db' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'domain.com',
        'port' => '3306',
        'username' => 'my_user',
        'password' => 'my_password',
        'database' => 'db2',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => false,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'log' => false,
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ],
```

I was able to: cake bake all assets (from the default database).
Since uppercase is not supported with cake bake all, I created manually: 
ExternalAssetsTable.php :

```
class ExternalAssetsTable extends Table {

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->ExternalAsset->setDataSource('external_db');
    $this->setTable('ASSET');
    $this->setDisplayField('NAME');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('ID');
```

Then, I tried to create the controller and the template views with:

```
cake bake controller external_assets
cake bake template external_assets
```

and with:
    cake bake controller ASSET -c external_db
    cake bake template ASSET -c external_db

and the code did not work.

My first question: What was wrong in my code?

---

My second need is the following:

"assets" contains data imported from ASSET, and other data entered manually in my database.

SERIAL may change occasionally, and I need to import it into assets. so foreach name = NAME, if serial <> SERIAL then serial := SERIAL.

In assets index.ctp and view.ctp, I need to show the following columns: id, name, serial, and the corresponding ASSET.NAME, ASSET.SERIAL if they exist.

I tried to add a function in AssetsController.php

```
public function getRemoteData(){
  $conn1 = ConnectionManager::get('k1000db'); #Remote Database 1
  $sql   = "SELECT * FROM  ASSET";
  $query = $conn1->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute();
  $result = $query->fetchAll(); #Here is the result
}
```

My question is: how to call this function in AssetsController index(), view() functions, and in Assets index.ctp ?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our SO Question Checklist to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Try first yourself, and then ask specific questions (i.e. why doesn't my code do what I am expecting).

Answer (score 0):

**In your first question:**

The `cake bake` make everything based on the tables that you have on your database, so, your code is:

```
cake bake ASSETS -c your_external_db_here
```

If use this code above, you check all the tables that you can `bake` by Cakephp:

```
cake bake -c your_external_db_here
```

And after you make it, manually rename your `ASSETS` to `ExternalAssets`, on `Controller`, `Template folder` and other things you `baked` to identify better the tables. But be careful to this `cake bake` doesn't replace your other `assets` that you baked before.

**In the second question:**

You will make a `Association`, in your AssetTable:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->hasOne('ExternalAssets')->setForeignKey('fk_here')->('pk_here');
    }
```

In your Controller:

```
public function index()
            {
                $assets = $this->Assets->find('all')
                ->select([ 'id', 'name', 'serial'])
                ->contain(['ExternalAssets' => [
                  'fields' => [
                      'NAME','SERIAL'
                     ]
                ]);
                //if you wanna paginate your resut
                //$assets = $this->paginate($assets);

                $this->set(compact('assets'));
                $this->set('_serialize', ['assets']);
            }

public function view($id = null)
    {
        $assets= $this->Assets->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);

        $this->set('assets', $assets);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['assets']);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks David. my external table is ASSET (without S). I tried: cake bake ASSET -c my_external_atabase and I got this error message:
Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my_external_database.a_s_s_e_t' doesn't exist

Comment: In `my_external_database` you replace for the name of your external database that you seted in the config. You was set like `external_db`. And sorry for the confusion that i made with your's databases name.

Comment: sure, I did it. the error is related to the table name: ASSET

Comment: the be precise: cake bake all ASSET external_db did not work

cake bake controller ASSET external_db worked

cake bake template ASSET external_db did not work

Comment: Try set `-c` before `ASSET`. And the `cake bake -c extenal_db` worked? (this list all of your's tables from `external_db`)

Comment: cake bake -c extenal_db worked and listed all the tables. But cake bake -c ASSET extenal_db did not work. It considered ASSET as the database name, which is not the case and gave an error.

Comment: cake bake all -c ASSET external_db gives the following error:  "Exception: The datasource configuration "ASSET" was not found."

Comment: ah i see the error, the format is `cake bake all ASSET -c external_db`, if not work, try without `-c external_db`

Comment: as I told in my first comment: cake bake all ASSET -c external_db gives an error: "Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'external_db.a_s_s_e_t' doesn't exist". The problem seems to be in the upper case and the fact that the table name is not in plural.

Comment: Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You solvd your question?

Comment: unfortunately, not yet. I'm blocked at the firrst question

Comment: Ok i will use the code of your question, and try to help you, when i'm at home. Later i will contact you for here in the comments. Bye!

Answer (score 0):

It was not possible for me to cake bake the external table because it did not respect the cakephp conventions. So as an alternative, I used this, in my index():

```
    $connection = ConnectionManager::get('db2');
    $machines = $connection->execute('SELECT * FROM MACHINE ORDER BY NAME ASC');
    $this->set(compact('machines'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['machines']);
```

then, I created the views manually.